# Why does this simple code yield 'Undefined variable: bar'

Tags: php, php-5.4

```
class A {
    protected $bar = 'bar';
    public function foo() {
        echo $this->$bar;
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->foo();
```

It's boggling my mind that this isn't working. I come from C++ and C# so it's likely something I don't understand about PHP.

Comment: Change `echo $this->$bar;` to `echo $this->bar;`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you access a member, you only need the dollar-sign before `this`; i.e. access it like this instead:

```
echo $this->bar;
```

Answer (score 6):

> Why does this simple code yield 'Undefined variable: bar'

Because PHP tries to evaluate the variable `$bar` before evaluating `$this->`. Since there is not a `$bar` variable, it yields a notice.

Remove the `$` in front of `$bar`:

```
echo $this->bar;
```

I would encourage you to read the [Variable Variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) section of the docs as well as [OOP Basics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).

Comment: I'm curious, why does dynamic language imply that specific order of evaluation?

Comment: It does not imply specific order of evaluation, more the variable variables. I mentioned it since you noted coming from C++. Which is far more static than PHP. Nonetheless, I have adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function(){
  echo $this->bar;
}
```

When use the $this then couln't use the symbol `$` before variable `$this->$variable`
but `$this->variable;`